# XSLT version in oracle weblogic 12.1.2.0.0

Tags: xslt, weblogic12c

I wanted to know the xslt version which is added with the weblogic 12.1.2.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>
```

to find out.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the preceding answer, I think that the default is an XSLT 1.0 processor, considering that the documentation (which is marginal) only links to the XSLT 1.0 spec.

Also:

> [*Configure an alternative XSLT transformer instead of the built-in transformer shipped in this version of WebLogic Server.*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/xml/xml_intro.html#177310)

Which means that you can configure any other (third party) XSLT transformation engine if you like.